# Upload 3 different featured image sizes to Wordpress

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

Is there a way that on Wordpress I can upload 3 different image sizes of my featured image? My post images are a different size in the first column rather than the second column, and I also have an owl carousel. In 2 out of the 3 places my featured image for my post gets distorted. So does anyone know how I can upload 3 different image sizes?

Here is what my site post layout looks like. As you can see at the top I have an owl carousel, in column 1 I have one post, and in column 2 I have three posts.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

You need to put this into your ***functions.php*** to register new image sizes. WP will automatically crop/resize the uploaded images to fit the sizes you have registered with `add_image_size`

*NOTE*

Images that already have been uploaded won't be affected by adding `add_image_size` **only new uploads will**. To overcome this without having to manually upload all images again, use a plugin like [Force Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/) that will recreate the images with all registered sizes done with `add_image_size`

Here's how to use it in it's most basic form, keeping the original ratio (no cropping, no distortion)

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180 );
```

Check out the link to the codex to learn more on how you can use the available parameters.